# Titanium 3.X getFile() from local storage

Tags: android, titanium, android-camera, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Using Titanium on Android 4+ I want to access a jpeg file which has been taken with the camera.  I need to achieve 2 objectives, namely, return the EXIF data and transfer the bytes to an API endpoint. My problem is I'm unable to access the file...

I'm using a 3rd party module to handle the file selection (Multi Image Picker) which returns a list of file locations, using the File Manager app on the emulator (GenyMotion) I can confirm the location on disk is correct.  However, the following always returns false...

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140901_083735.jpg');
Ti.API.info('Do we have a file? ' (file.exists()? 'YES' : 'NO'));
```

The output for the above would be... **Do we have a file? NO**

Further reading shows Titanium has 5 predefined folder locations which can be passed into the getFile() method and one possible reason for the above code not working would be it is defaulting to the 'Resouces' folder location?  That said all but one folder location is app specific, the exception being externalStorageLocation.  Now my understanding of an Android device is that any image taken with the camera will be stored on the internal storage system unless an SD card is present.  This is true in my case as the following lists 0 files...

```
var extDir = Ti.Filesystem.getExternalStorageDirectory();
var dir = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(extDir);
var dir_files = dir.getDirectoryListing();

Ti.API.info('External files... ' + dir_files.length);
```

The output for the above would be... **External files... 0**

So am I right in thinking Appcelerator have simply not included the ability to access local storage (outside of any app specific folders) within their API? Or am I missing something and there is in fact another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bharal I was able to find a solution...

By using the Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery() method I was able to identify the correct native path  for the image by inspecting the event object returned from the success callback.

The path was missing 'file://' at the beginning, I couldn't be 100% sure but I suspect this forces the getFile() method to use an absolute path and not a relative path from within the Resources folder.

To confirm, the following will return a file object...

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('file://[path]');
```

Where [path] is the folder location as reported within the File Manager app on the device, for example '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140901_083735.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

Yah mon, i dunno.

Here is wat i used when i was doin pictures on my Ti app, but then i got rid of that section because i realised i didn't need to be doin pictures. Pictures mon, dey ain' what you want sometimes, yo?

```
    Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({ //dissall jus' open up a piccha selectin' ting. ez.
        success:function(event){
            var image = event.media;
            if (event.mediaType==Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO){
//so image.nativePath is the path to the image. 
// profileImg be jus' some Ti.UI.createImageView ting yo be puttin in yo' page.
//meyybe yo be wantin' alert(image.nativePath); here too, dat be helpin?
                profileImg.image = image.nativePath; 
            }

        },
        cancel:function(){
            //we cancelled out, why we doin' that?
        }    
    });
```

Now that isn't going to really be helpin' you, but yo can use that to see wat the native path yo piccha be usin' be, and then be seein' if maybe what yo be puttin' in yo code be sam ting.

Jus' wrap the above as an addEventListener("click", function(){ ... } ); on sam ting in yo page, and jus' add sam element to put th' piccha in if yo be wantin' to see the piccha but i be tellin' you picchas mon, sometimes dey ain' worth time.

But meyybe yo wantin' use not an emulator for dis ting, dey can be actin' weird yo should be usin some small phone maybe? Dat way you can be findin' if yo got dem memory leeks and meyybe some memory sprouts, an memory onions too.

Comment: Thanks @bharal, this set me on the right path to solve the problem.  I'd +1 if I could.

Comment: @AdrianHolmes glad it helped - the caipirinha i had before i wrote my answer helped me channel the spirit of an ancient cool dood to answer your question. VoodooJones is probably the real hero here.